# Putting a border around the selected list item

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have an HTML list. The goal is that:

1. When an `li` is clicked, the `.my-list--selected` class will be applied. And, since the inner div also has a border-bottom, the `.border-bottom` class must be removed (or else it appears as though there is a 2px wide border along the bottom if both classes are applied).
2. When another `li` is clicked, the previously selected `li`'s `.my-list--selected` is removed and the `.border-bottom` class is reinstated (there can only be 1 '.my-list--selected' at a time).

I've written the below code and it works, but it seems really messy and overly complicated to me.

Is there a better way to go about achieving this goal?

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  //Remove the my-list--selected class from any elements that already have it
  $('.my-list--selected').removeClass('my-list--selected');
  //Add the .border-bottom class back to any element that is missing it
  $('.my-list--selected').addClass('border-bottom');
  //Add the my-list--selected class to the clicked element
  $(this).addClass('my-list--selected');
  //Remove the border-bottom class from the clicked element
  $(this).find('.border-bottom').removeClass('border-bottom');
});
```

```css
li div {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.my-list--selected {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please check this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ykx0a89n/) and [demo 2](https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ykx0a89n/1/). Let me know which one work for you.

Comment: @Tushar hey, yes! Demo 2 is close to what I need. I'm sorry, I should have been clearer in my question - the div has padding-left on it making its border-bottom shorter than the li around it. I thin your Demo 2 is close though and can use some of it.

Comment: @MeltingDog Please do not add or change the code in your question after you have received answers, as to not invalidate them. You are welcome to ask a new question with your improvements and/or new code. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Are you required to have the `.border-bottom` class on the `div` elements?  I'd move those up to the `li` elements so you don't have to bother with the add/remove `.border-bottom` and you could use [first-child](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) to cleanly add a top border for the selected element if it's first (and avoid a double border for the other items).  See below snippet with the changes.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  //Remove the my-list--selected class from any elements that already have it
  $('.my-list--selected').removeClass('my-list--selected');
  //Add the my-list--selected class to the clicked element
  $(this).addClass('my-list--selected');
});
```

```css
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.my-list--selected {
  border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-right: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.my-list--selected:first-child {
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
  <li class="border-bottom">
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I am required to have border-bottom on the divs. In the project there is a padding-left and padding-right on the div, so the border-bottom actually appears shorter than the border around the li

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason for the jQuery code to mess around with the `border-bottom` class.  There is no harm in letting the selected item have more than one class simultaneously.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  //Remove the my-list--selected class from any elements that already have it
  $('.my-list--selected').removeClass('my-list--selected');
  //Add the my-list--selected class to the clicked element
  $(this).addClass('my-list--selected');
});
```

```css
.border-bottom {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.my-list--selected {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="border-bottom">Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

---

I echo @P.Albert's recommendation not to put `class="border-bottom"` on each list item — it's unnecessarily tedious.  Either style all `li` elements, or on children of certain `ul` elements.

Assuming that you might have multiple lists on a page, and that selections on lists should act independently, I recommend clearing the `my-list--selected` class on siblings of the clicked element, rather than all elements on the page with the `my-list--selected` class.

```js
$("li").click(function() {
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('my-list--selected');
  $(this).addClass('my-list--selected');
});
```

```css
ul.border-bottom > li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.my-list--selected {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="border-bottom">
  <li>
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div>Content</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Ah yes, I do know what you mean - but the problem here is the padding on the div element. The desired effect is the bottom border is shorter than the select border, hence why it's attached to a different element.

Sorry, it's my fault for not making that clear in the first place.